# Jquery slidedown menu issues

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate my wordpress sub-menu with Jquery.

Here's what I am trying to mimic: http://money.co.uk

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $("#main-nav li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bNeDh/

It seems to be the reverse of what I want, I'd like the children to slide down when user mouseover the parent.
My jquery isn't great at all, can anyone provide the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your CSS a bit... 
If you find this (or any) answer useful Accept it by clicking checkmark.

You probably want something like this:

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EbDYR/)**

```
$("#main-nav li").hover(function () {
$(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown("fast");
},function(){
$(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for starters, if you want to just be toggling the children, you should specify that with the selector. you'd want to have the first ul's li only to be bound to the event handler. otherwise the toggle occurs when you hover over every single li in the #main-nav div.

```
$("#menu-top-navigation ul > li").hover(function () {
    $'.sub-menu').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

then, if you want subnavs under the first two main items, put a ul under then full of options.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm going to spend the next few weeks going through the jquery documentation and try and bind together the fragmented bits of knowlege I have, probably should have done that before asking here, thank's again anyway.

Comment: honestly one of the most important things with jquery is learning how the selectors work. remember, google and stackoverflow are your best friends for reference and help.